# Grafana Query challenge for $ and ^

Tags: grafana, grafana-templating

I was reading some of the query on grafana dashboard.

There is one query I am not quite understand

```
sum (container_memory_working_set_bytes{pod_name=~"^$Pod$"}) / sum (machine_memory_bytes{kubernetes_io_hostname=~"^$Node$"}) * 100
```

I understand the $Pod is my valuable or template which I created.

But I am not sure what does the "^" and the second "$" in "^$Node$" mean.

Thank you for help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know nothing about Grafana, but that definitely looks like a Regular Expression. If I'm right, `$Pod` and `$Node` are mere placeholders that will be substituted with their actual values at runtime, and the `^` and `$` mean that you want to match exactly that value. In other words, in order to match, a string has to begin and end with that value.

As an example, if `$Pod` gets substituted by, say, `foo_pod`, a string containing exactly `foo_pod` will match, but a string like `foo_pod2` will not.

[Here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) you can learn more about Regular Expressions, specifically about the `^` and `$` anchors.